# Understanding typesafety anomaly with Java generics

Tags: java, generics, java-8

I have following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> s = new ArrayList<String>();
    s.add("kshitiz");

    //This is not typesafe. It should blow up at runtime
    List<Integer> i = new ArrayList(s);
    System.out.println(i.get(0));
}
```

This program runs fine and it prints `kshitiz`. It only fails if I replace the last line with:

```
System.out.println(i.get(0).getClass());
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

What is happening here?

Comment: Please specify Java version

Comment: What exception does it throw?

Comment: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer`

Comment: You are ignoring some critical compiler warnings. Your IDE or the compiler should warn you about accessing a raw type.

Comment: That's not his question, @Turing85. His point is that he would expect `i.get(0)` to fail because he expects it to cast the object to an `Integer`.

Comment: It's explained well here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27606449/how-exactly-do-generics-work

Answer (score 13):

I guess you are aware, that generic types are gone at run time. Now, to see what's happening behind the scenes, let's look at this piece of code

```
public static Class<?> getClass(final Object object) {
    return object.getClass();
}

public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final List<String> s = new ArrayList<String>();
    s.add("kshitiz");

    // This is not typesafe. It should blow up at runtime
    final List<Integer> i = new ArrayList(s);
    System.out.println(getClass(i.get(0)));
    System.out.println(i.get(0).getClass());
}
```

and the output of javap -c

```
  [...]
  26: getstatic     #8                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
  29: aload_2
  30: iconst_0
  31: invokeinterface #9,  2            // InterfaceMethod java/util/List.get:(I)Ljava/lang/Object;
  36: invokestatic  #10                 // Method getClass:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Class;
  39: invokevirtual #11                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
  42: getstatic     #8                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
  45: aload_2
  46: iconst_0
  47: invokeinterface #9,  2            // InterfaceMethod java/util/List.get:(I)Ljava/lang/Object;
  52: checkcast     #12                 // class java/lang/Integer
  55: invokevirtual #2                  // Method java/lang/Object.getClass:()Ljava/lang/Class;
  58: invokevirtual #11                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
  61: return
```

So you see that in the second call, the String is cast to an Integer, while in the first case, it is regarded as an object.
Thus as long as the String is handled just like any other object, everything is fine, but as soon as you call a method of the element type of the list, the object is cast to that type.

Comment: It is interesting why compiler put this unnecessary cast.

Answer (score 0):

Generics in java are broken by design.

In your `List<Integer> i = new ArrayList(s);` you have a raw `ArrayList`. It means that you ignore type parameter and it works like if it was an `Object`. Then you (implicitly) cast an `ArrayList`  to `List<Integer>`, but generics are not checked at runtime, so the JVM doesn't care about mismatch.

When you do `System.out.println(i.get(0))` you don't convert `String` to `Integer` because 'println(Object)` method is invoked.

In `System.out.println(i.get(0).getClass())` this magic brakes because for some reason (you probably can find this reason in specs, but I suggest you not to) your `String` gets casted to `Integer`.

Comment: You may discuss whether it’s better if the code fails at the assignment of `ArrayList` to `ArrayList<Integer>` or, as it did, when calling `get`, however, I do not see enough difference to justify calling the current behavior “broken by design”. After all, the result is the same, ignoring a compile-time warning leads to a runtime exception…